# where am gonna wrong with search?

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
def userlogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('userlogin'))

def Search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search=request.GET['srch']
        if search:
                match=Blog.objects.filter(Q( blog_title_icontains=search)|
                                      Q( blog_description_icontains=search)|
                                      Q(blogcategories_icontains=search) )
                if match:
                    return render (request,"search.html",{"sr":match})
                else:
                      messages.error(request,"no results found")
        else:
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/search/')

    return render (request,'index.html')
```

#

index.html

```
<form action="{%url 'search' %}" method="post" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 header-search">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search here..." name="Search" required="">
                    <button class="btn btn1 my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

blog/urls.py

```
path('search/', views.Search, name='search'),
```

*****it gives me error:

```
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'srch'
```

please help me how can i search in my blog by using existing template.

Comment: I am not good at python but looks like `request.GET['srch']` giving you an error since your `input` field has different `name`. `<input ... name="Search"/>`

Comment: i tried as you said but it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors.

Your search field is called `Search`, not `srch`.  I don't know where you got `srch` from since you never use it in the template.

Your form is being submitted by POST, but you are trying to get the data from the GET.

But in fact a search form should be submitted by GET, not POST, since it is not making changes in the backend and could conceivably be cached.

So you need:

```
<form action="{%url 'search' %}" method="get" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 header-search">
```

...

```
def Search(request):
    search=request.GET['Search']
    if search:
```

Comment: could you please help me how can i add search functionality in my weblog by using inbuilt searching form in template.

Comment: i did the exact as you mentioned but it didn't wok